# Where does "rel=0" get removed from my YouTube parameters?

Tags: php

I prefer using &rel=0 as a YouTube parameter so that only MY videos get listed in the "More Videos" feature.

I have been using the following string in the WordPress editor for a couple of years and it has worked until a day or two ago.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRw1q6aJtnQ&rel=0

Yes, many places inside WordPress "help" in converting that string to what some developer assumes I want, and removes the "rel=0" parameter.  Today's result is an iframe like this:

```
<iframe title="Stress Pattern: 2-syllable verbs" width="700" height="394" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PRw1q6aJtnQ?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```

What code stripped the "rel=0" ... and added all those strange "allow" parms?

Comment: This isn't something WP allows you to do unless you have the `unfiltered_html` capability, aka if you're an admin or a super admin on a multisite, and isn't how you're meant to do this. WP is supposed to strip things like iframes out of your content.

Comment: Also, the `rel` parameter changed in 2018, it doesn't mean the same thing https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018, which editor are you using? What did you change a day or two ago that triggered this? ( this wouldn't have just started happening unless code changed, unless you're actually on WordPress.com or a managed host? That's important info to know ), and how are you embedding it into the post? There are several ways to embed things from youtube, but you didn't state which one you were using

Comment: First:  yes, rel=0 changed back in 2018, and I know exactly how it changed, I prefer the behavior it has had since that change.  That's why I use it.

Comment: Second: the iframe code was produced by WordPress, not me.  It's a fallacy to think that WordPress strips out iframes when it actually produces them for valid reasons.

Third: The editor is the Visual editor, non-Gutenberg.

What I changed that triggered this is NOTHING.   WP base code and plugins are changing constantly.  WP is producing different code in that iframe now than it did a few days ago 

My question stands: Where does that code come from?

Comment: Vitauts is correct: this is oEmbed. If you go to your video page on YouTube and search the page source for 'oEmbed' you'll find two links for json+oembed and xml+oembed: open one of those and you'll see the YouTube-provided iframe, e.g. here's the JSON version: https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPRw1q6aJtnQ

Comment: WP strips iframes out of post content prior to running the shortcodes and embeds, that's why if you copy paste an iframe into the posts html and save it gets removed. This doesn't happen if you have the `unfiltered_html` capability though, aka if you're a super admin on a multisite, or an admin on a single site. Those users can enter whatever they like in the post content. `wp_kses_post` is the function that performs the tag whtielisting. It's also how OEmbeds etc can generate iframe markup, but you won't find that markup in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iframe content is generated by youtube itself, wordpress just requests it via oembed call. If you wish you can study `wp-includes/class-oembed.php` code, but that will not help you to change iframe parameters. For that you may apply `embed_oembed_html` filter, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_oembed_html/. It receives iframe html code, so you can do some string replacements to change it.

Comment: Thank You Vitauts Stočka!
Thanks also Rup, for the confirmation. 
 
I came to the same conclusion about the same time Viauts and Rup posted. The YouTube oembed processor created the iframe code ... and as of 2 days ago started dropping the rel=0 parm.

Comment: I have also found that WordPress WILL accept an iframe block for YouTube.com.  With that, I can construct my own iframe call to YouTube with the parameters I prefer, bypassing not only oEmbed, but the other "helpful" modules in WordPress that want to alter YouTube calls.

Comment: The following works!  ...when entered into the "Text" tab of the TinyMCE editor.  Yes, if one switches back and forth between the Text tab and the Visual tab, the code gets rewritten some, but only by adding a useless span, not by changing the desired call to YouTube.

    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NsSxWP7QNcw?rel=0" width="700" height="394" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

THANKS again Vitauts and Rup!